# Any Sequence of a Measurable Sets Has a Convergent Subsequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

For each $n\geq 1$, let $A_n$ be a measurable (Borel) set in the unit interval $I=[0, 1]$.

> Does there necessarily exist a subsequence $(A_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ of $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that the characteristic functions $\chi_{A_{n_k}}$ converge pointwise to $\chi_A$ for some measurable subset $A$ of $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n$ be the union of the intervals $[j/2^n, (j+1)/2^n)$ for *even* values of $j$, $0\le j<2^n$. Define $$r_n=2\chi_{A_n}-1,$$so $r_n$ is just the $n$th Rademacher function.

If we had $A_{n_j}\to A$ almost everywhere then $r_{n_j}\to f=2\chi_A-1$ almost everywhere. Dominated convergence then shows that $||r_{n_j}-f||_1\to0$, which is impossible because $||r_n-r_m||_1=1/2$ for $n\ne m$.

Comment: That's a very nice answer. I'll wait for some more time before accepting.

Comment: I just realized this: Let $T$ be a measure preserving strong-mixing transformation $T:X\to X$, where $X$ is a probability space. Let $A_0\subseteq X$ be of positive measure. Define $A_n=T^{-1}(A_0)$. Then we cannot find an $A\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(A_n\Delta A)\to 0$. This is because by strong-mixing we have $\mu(A_n\cap A)\to \mu(A)\cap \mu(A_0)$. The particular example which you have given arises by taking $T:I\to I$ as $T(x)=2x\pmod{1}$ and $A_0=[0, 1/2]$.

Comment: When I wrote "Define $A_n=T^{-1}(A_0)$ ...", I meant "Define $A_n=T^{-n}(A_0) ...$".