# For the sequence of sets $A_n = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{2^{n-1}} \bigg[\frac{2j - 1}{2^n}, \frac{2j}{2^n}\bigg]$ does $\lim_n A_n$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

For the sequence of sets $A_n = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{2^{n-1}} \bigg[\frac{2j - 1}{2^n}, \frac{2j}{2^n}\bigg]$ does $\lim_n A_n$ exist? If that exists, what is the structure of the limiting set? And what about the measurability of that limiting set?

Comment: welcome to ME ... how would you define limits of sequences of sets ? You need some topology.

Comment: I am thinking like what if we take elements in the limiting set to be the pointwise limit. Are we allowed to do that?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName (and RhL): The definition of the limit of a sequence of sets is purely set-theoretic, not topological: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any Sequence of a Measurable Sets Has a Convergent Subsequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832340/any-sequence-of-a-measurable-sets-has-a-convergent-subsequence) See the accepted answer. It proves that (a minor variant of) your sequence has no (set-theoretic) limit, and even that no subsequence has a limit.

Comment: @AnneBauval : OK so set-theoretic limit.

Comment: The trouble is that there are nonequivalent notions of limits of sequences of sets. You have to work out which one you mean. What you wrote so far is not enough.